# Relative velocity of 2 ships

Tags: vectors, angle

I have 2 ships. For each of these ships, I have their speed over ground, course over ground (relative to north), and current location (x,y).

How do I calculate their relative velocity?

The questions relates to the first step in the projection algorithm described in [this paper](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/273123985_Assessment_of_ship_collision_estimation_methods_using_AIS_data)

Comment: I believe it's the vector difference of their velocities over ground.

Comment: @BobbieD can you please elaborate (i.e. formula, given what I have)?

Comment: You define two vectors $\vec v_\text{boat 1} = (v_1\sin(\theta),v_1\cos(\theta))$ and similarly for $\vec v_\text{boat 2}$.  Here $v_1$ is the speed of boat $1$ and $\theta$ is the angle between the direction it's heading and North.  Then relative velocity is $\vec v_\text{rel} = \vec v_\text{boat 1} - \vec v_\text{boat 2}$.  And if you just want a number then you find the magnitude by the Pythagorean theorem.

Comment: First you have to decide: relative to which of the two ships?

Comment: Robert Heinlein once wrote that collision detection is easy: the blip grows but doesn’t move. I.e., the distance decreases but the relative bearing doesn’t change.

Comment: Assuming $\left\vert\vec{v}\right\vert \ll c:\ \mbox{light velocity}$ or/and $c \to \infty$.

Comment: @BobbieD looks like your comment is what I need; will you make it an answer? If so, please also explain what the velocity units of Vboat1 would be (looks like (distance^2/time, distance^2/time) and the magnitude would be in the same units?). What confuses me is the following: is speed a vector? or the magnitude of a vector?

Comment: The relative velocity $\vec V_{BA}$ is defined in equation (5) in the cited paper.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to know if you know about taking scalar projections. Effectively their relative speed will be the difference of their cosine projections. But please elaborate what prerequisite knowledge you have in this field so as to answer your problem better.

Comment: This might’ve been better as a comment.

Comment: I know, but through the android app for stack overflow I can't comment on certain answers. Is there an FAQ or tutorial available for this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: @user363203 It is safe to assume I have 0 knowledge, even though I studied these things a while back. I am just trying to implement the algorithm in that paper. Bobbie D seems to have answered the question

Comment: You can leave comments once you have 50 reputation.